# Query returns results 5 times

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

I have a weird problem. My query in C#/ASP.NET returns results 5 times. I tried brakepoint-ing but I can't find the error. I have 2 related tables. One table loads on PAGE_LOAD and when the user click on a cell, it shows the content from another table related to that cell. It's very simple.

```
    //PAGE LOAD
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + dbpath + "/secure_user/data/data.mdb");
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Project,Manager,Customer,Deadline FROM projects WHERE Username='" + uname + "'", myConnection);
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(table);
        adapter.Dispose();
        GridView1.DataSource = table;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

It loads projects table to the GridView. Now when I click a certain project, it displays more information about that project:

> ```
> protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
>     GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
>     Label1.Text = row.Cells[1].Text;
> ```

```
    OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + dbpath + "/secure_user/data/data.mdb");
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT tasks.Task,tasks.Priority,tasks.Done,taska.Hours FROM projects,tasks WHERE tasks.Username='" + uname + "' AND tasks.Project='" + Label1.Text + "'", myConnection);
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(table);
    adapter.Dispose();
    GridView2.DataSource = table;
    GridView2.DataBind();
    GridView2.Visible = true;
}
```

It displays with no error, but it does 5 times no matter what project I select from GridView1, it always displays GridView2 (second table) content 5 times in a row. What could be the problem?

Comment: There seems to be a typo in the second SELECT statement (taska).

Comment: by the way, this kind of query is a easy target for scripting attacks; please refrain from using page editable fields content without validations.

Comment: someone needs to read about little bobby tables...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you have something wrong in your query. Try using INNER JOIN instead of ,.

Instead of this:

```
SELECT tasks.Task, tasks.Priority, tasks.Done, tasks.Hours
FROM projects, tasks
WHERE tasks.Username='" + uname + "' AND tasks.Project='" + Label1.Text + "'
```

Try this:

```
SELECT tasks.Task, tasks.Priority, tasks.Done, tasks.Hours
FROM projects INNER JOIN tasks ON projects.ID = tasks.ProjectID --> may not be correct depends on your table structure
WHERE tasks.Username='" + uname + "' AND tasks.Project='" + Label1.Text + "'
```

Another thing: building a SQL query like that is prone to [SQL Injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: wow, that works perfect! thank you very much! I wish I could vote you up but I'm missing another 14reps. Thank you!

I'll consider SQL injection prevention. Thank you everybody.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing cross join between the `projects` table and the `tasks` table, so you are joining every project with each task for the project that you selected. As you have five projects you get each task five times.

Use a join to specify the relation between the `projects` table and the `tasks` table:

```
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(
   "SELECT tasks.Task,tasks.Priority,tasks.Done,taska.Hours "+
   "FROM projects "+
   "INNER JOIN tasks ON tasks.Project = projects.Project "+
   "WHERE projects.Username='" + uname + "' AND projects.Project='" + Label1.Text + "'", myConnection);
```

Note:
Notice that I used the Username field in the `projects` table rather than the `tasks` table. Either you have redundancy in the tables, or the fields mean different things. If some other user can add tasks to your project you would need a condition for the `tasks.Username` field also if you only want to see the tasks that you added yourself.

Comment: See the note that I added, there are some differences from the query that Adrian suggested...

Answer (score 0):

Could be that this query is returning multiple records; can you list primary keys in the used tables

Answer (score 0):

In your second query you have a join, of sorts. You never return anything in the SELECT from the projects table, but it is referenced in the query. I'm guessing that you have 5 projects.

Also, you are injecting data into the query. This is bad as it becomes very easy for an attacker to mount a SQL Injection attack against your code and database, especially as you are using data directly from controls. You should consider using at least parameterised queries.

Comment: I understand that. I'll read more about SQL injection. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You try adding to your query DISTINCT clause. Because if it is not presented, your query did a cartesian product.

OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT tasks.Task,tasks.Priority,tasks.Done,taska.Hours FROM projects,tasks WHERE tasks.Username='" + uname + "' AND tasks.Project='" + Label1.Text + "'", myConnection);

Comment: I already solved this but I'll take that into consideration. Thanks.